# conditional references in visual studio - how to define the customized variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reference, msbuild

I have a project which should reference other projects 
done it this way:

```
 <Reference Include="referencedDll" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
  <HintPath>..\Resources\External DLLs\referencedDll.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

this works fine and copies the dll just in case it is in debug.
but I want it not to depend on debug/ release but some other variable definition

something like:

```
<Reference Include="referencedDll" Condition=" '$(ReleaseType)' == 'INTERNAL_RELEASE' ">
  <HintPath>..\Resources\External DLLs\referencedDll.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

I did not find how to define the ReleaseType variable? 
+ is there any way to use the same variable for both #if in the code and for conditional referencing?

I saw the option to use  use

```
 Condition=" $(DefineConstants.Contains('INTERNAL_RELEASE'))"
```

but it did not work as I'd expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure if there is a way to do that in Visual studio.
If you are running the build from msbuild directly you can use /P:ReleaseType=INTERNAL_RELEASE.

In my project I ended up changing Configuration property and instead of having it as Debug and Release I have more values like , DEV,QA,STAGE, etc...

Comment: nice idea -  how to you chnage the configuration property? and then can you use it also from scripts?

Comment: Go to Solution->Configuration Manager and you will see all the projects with the configurations. The drop down for active solution configurations contains entry <New>, make sure to copy the new entry from Debug or Release. From the script you can use it by msbuid your-project-name /p:Configuration=YOUR_CONFIGURATION